# How to draw default postion on the google map in android?

Tags: android

Current the google map display US as default.
 [image]

I want to dispaly India as default on the map.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `getController()` on your `MapView` to get a `MapController`, then call `setCenter()` to set the center of the map to whatever coordinates you like. You may also want to call `setZoom()` to control the zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, like this "

```
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    mapController.animateTo(point);
    mapController.setZoom(6);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapView.invalidate();
```